# Indexes with the same object_id but different names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index

When I run

```
SELECT
  count(object_id) AS count,
  object_id,
  min(name) as name1,
  max(name) AS name2
FROM
  sys.indexes
GROUP BY object_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY count
```

I will get a list of indexes having the same `object_id`, but not necessarily with the same name.

Should not all indexes with the same `object_id` have the same name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The `Object_ID` belongs to the object the index belongs to, such as an indexed view or a table.**

When you look at the `object_id` in the `sys.indexes` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> object_id  - ID of the object to which this index belongs.

If you want to uniquely identify the index you need the `Object_ID` + `index_id` columns or the `index_id` for a specific `object_id`.

To verify this, you can add the `OBJECT_NAME()` function to your query

```
SELECT
  count(object_id) AS count,
  object_id,
  OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
  min(name) as name1,
  max(name) AS name2
FROM
  sys.indexes
GROUP BY object_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY count;
```